# Linking error (involving a DirectX library) using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker, directx, directx-10

I'm trying to look at a DirectX example provided to me by my University, however when I try to compile it (in Debug mode) in Visual Studio 2008 it gives me the following error -

> Error 1   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3d10.lib,'

I'm not sure what the problem could be. I have another DirectX example from the same module which I have worked on extensively and not had this problem with.

I have ensured that Visual Studio knows where to look for linked files, by setting the directories to \include and \Lib\x86 in the VC Directories.

I have also gone to the solution properties and added the following files to Properties->Linker->Input

> d3d10.lib, d3dx10d.lib, dxerr.lib, dxguid.lib

(Both of these things are the same for the other example, and it compiles and works perfectly)

Any suggestions as to what might be the problem would be much appreciated - Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Install the directx sdk on your pc after make sure that your linker paths contains the path where the d3d10.lib,..., dxguid.lib are.

Comment: As I stated above, the other example which uses DirectX works perfectly well and has these same properties. Of course the paths contain these .lib files.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the d3d10.lib in your pc? Do you have the access to this file>

Comment: Yes, of course. I have done plenty of work on the other DirectX project (so of course have the DirectX SDK installed), which is working fine; and I have checked the directory myself to make sure.